# use custom function configuration option of a jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this jQuery plugin: http://demo.awkwardgroup.com/showcase/

I am trying to show a counter on the first slide of Awkward Showcase and have been unable to nest the call into the script without breaking it to some degree or other.  I tried using current_id, but realized that the value of current_id was inconsistent, at least, when I was calling for it.  I am now trying to rely on the "active" state of the number 1, which corresponds to the first slide and is consistent.

I realize now that it has a custom_function feature, but don't know how to plug this in there

```
var awNavButtonID = document.getElementById('showcase-navigation-button-1');
function myHack() {
var awNavButtonClass = awNavButtonID.className;         
if(awNavButton == 'active'){
    document.getElementById('defaultCountdown').style.left = "250px"; 
    } else {
    document.getElementById('defaultCountdown').style.left = "-9999px";
    }
}



$(document).ready(function(){
$("#showcase").awShowcase(
{
    content_width:  700,
    content_height: 470,
    custom_function: null //how do i plug it in here?
});
});
```

Comment: `custom_function: myHack` or  `custom_function: function() {...}` will do as far as pugging in goes. I don't understand your question fully though, hence not putting this as an answer.

Comment: whats your exact requirement? not able to understand clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind myHack function to the custom_function callback, try this :

```
$("#showcase").awShowcase(
{
    content_width:  700,
    content_height: 470,
    custom_function: myhack
});
```

You can also attach your function to a local variable.

```
var myHackFunction = function myHack() { ... }
... 
custom_function: myHackFunction
```

Finally, you can implement an anonymous function :

```
custom_function: function() { /* do stuff here */ }
```